# get index of filtered array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

how to get the index of filtered array?

for example I wanna to get the index of even number

```
  let nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

  let filterNum = nums.filter(num=> num %2 ==0);

  console.log(filterNum);
```

Comment: Try doing this: `let nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let filterNum = nums.filter(num=> num %2 ==0);
let filterIndex = filterNum.map(item=>nums[item]);
console.log(filterIndex);` **Only if there aren't duplicates**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.reduce`:

```js
const nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
const filterNum = nums.reduce((acc, num, index) => {
  if(num%2 === 0) acc.push(index);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(filterNum);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get the keys from the array and filter by checking the value.

```js
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    evenIndices = [...nums.keys()].filter(i => nums[i] % 2 === 0);

console.log(evenIndices);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the index, try passing a second argument to your filter callback like this:

```
 let nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let filterNum = nums.filter( (num,index) => {
  if(num %2 ==0){
    console.log('index', index)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

*Filter Function can accept optional argument*

> "The index of the current element being processed in the array."

```
let nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let filterNum = nums.filter((num,i)=> {
        num %2 ==0
        if ( num %2 ==0) console.log(i);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this relatively easily with `.flatMap`:

```js
const evenIndices = (ns) =>
  ns .flatMap ((n, i) => n % 2 == 0 ? [i] : [])

console .log (evenIndices ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]))
```

But there is a strong reason to abstract this a bit to create a `filterMap` function using the same technique, and writing `evenIndices` based on that:

```js
const filterMap = (f, m) => (xs) =>
  xs .flatMap ((x, i, a) => f (x, i, a) ? [m (x, i, a)] : [])

const evenIndices = filterMap (
  n => n % 2 == 0, 
  (_, i) => i
) 

console .log (evenIndices ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]))
```

This is more code, but the `filterMap` function is a genuinely reusable function and it makes for a nicer implementation of `evenIndices`.

Answer (score 0):

Index is passed to filter function as a second parameter, example:

```
let nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let filteredNums = nums.filter((number, index) => index %2 == 0);
console.log(filteredNums);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would get the first index of an even number

```js
const nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
const evenNumIndex = nums.findIndex(num => num % 2 === 0);

// and to access the number
const evenNum = nums[evenNumIndex];
```

Or to get an array of all the even numbers you can do this

```
const evenNumIndexes = nums.reduce((memo, num, index) => {
   if(num % 2 === 0) {
      memo.push(index);
   }
   return memo;
}, []);
```